# How can I get back the string from its BoW vector?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, string-matching

I have generated BoW for a pandas dataframae column called `tech_raw_data['Product lower']`.

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
smer_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(tech_raw_data['Product lower'].values.astype('U'))
smer_vocab = count_vect.get_feature_names()
```

Next to test string similarities with this BoW vectors I created BoW for only one entry in a column in a dataframe, toys['ITEM NAME'].

```
 toys = pd.read_csv('toy_data.csv', engine='python')
 print('-'*80)
 print(toys['ITEM NAME'].iloc[0])
 print('-'*80)
 inp = [toys['ITEM NAME'].iloc[0]]

 cust_counts = count_vect.transform(inp)
 cust_vocab = count_vect.get_feature_names()
```

Checking similarities:

```
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

for x in cust_counts[0].toarray():
    for y in smer_counts.toarray():
        ratio = similar(x, y)
        #print(ratio)
        if ratio>=0.85:
            should print the string corresponding to BoW y
```

Now whenever the match ratio exceeds 0.85, I need to print the string corresponding to the `smer_counts` in `tech_raw_data['Product lower']` dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in cust_counts[0].toarray():
    for i, y in enumerate(smer_counts.toarray()):
        ratio = similar(x, y)
        #print(ratio)
        if ratio>=0.85:
            print (tech_raw_data.loc[i, 'Product lower'])
```

Enumerate the numpy array returned by `smer_counts.toarray()` and use the index when the `ratio>=0.85` to get the corresponding text in the `tech_raw_data` dataframe.

This is valid because `len(smer_counts.toarray()) == len(tech_raw_data)` and also the order of records in the dataframe is preserved.